# How to kill background process in android

Tags: android, taskmanager

I am working on Battery saver app. my task is to close backround running apps installed by the user. I have read almost every thread regarding this topic but not find any solution at all.

I tried with different things to kill process by process id like `android.os.Process.killProcess(process.pid)`, by sending signal to OS like `android.os.Process.sendSignal(process.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL)`, by killing `activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("package_name")`, by restarting package name `activityManager.restartPackage("package_name)`.

I can't get these solutions to work. I know it is possible because we can force stop application by going into settings.

Comment: perhaps explaining why you need to do this would more encourage people to help answer, because it sounds like your app is malicious.

Comment: JoxTraex, I am working on Battery saver app. my task is to close backround running apps

Comment: when you use SIGNAL KILL, did background process die then created automatically or they didn't affected from signal ?

Comment: ozi ..They didn't affected from signal.